# extracting the outermost boundary without using contour extraction

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project where I have a binary image (like the one below) of hand, and I want to extract only the boundary to train a machine learning algorithm.

Since I am implementing this in real-time and there can be a lot of error contours inside the boundary, therefore using contour extraction technique in opencv slows the program down.

I have tried using morphological closing operation followed by simple edge detection, however still I find a lot of information inside the outer boundary.

[image]
[image: This is am example of the silhouette image extracted]
[image]
[image]

I am using kinect sensor to track the hand, and therefore these error value can not be corrected using a preprocessing technique.

The function I have written to try to solve this problem is:

```
Mat CvHandRegion::sampleBoundaryPoints(Mat input)
{
        Mat sampledOut;
sampledOut.create(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8U);
sampledOut.setTo(0);

for( int x = 0; x < input.cols; x += C_SAMPLING_STEP)
{
    for( int y = 0; y < input.rows; y += C_SAMPLING_STEP)
    {
        if(input.at<uchar>(y,x) == 255)
        {
            sampledOut.at<uchar>(y,x) = 255;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for( int x = 0; x < input.cols; x += C_SAMPLING_STEP)
{
    for( int y = input.rows-1; y > 0; y -= C_SAMPLING_STEP)
    {
        if(input.at<uchar>(y,x) == 255)
        {
            sampledOut.at<uchar>(y,x) = 255;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for( int y = 0; y < input.rows; y += C_SAMPLING_STEP)
{
    for( int x = 0; x < input.cols; x += C_SAMPLING_STEP)
    {
        if(input.at<uchar>(y,x) == 255)
        {
            sampledOut.at<uchar>(y,x) = 255;
            break;
        }
    }
}


for( int y = 0; y < input.rows; y += C_SAMPLING_STEP)
{
    for( int x = input.cols-1; x > 0; x -= C_SAMPLING_STEP)
    {
        if(input.at<uchar>(y,x) == 255)
        {
            sampledOut.at<uchar>(y,x) = 255;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return sampledOut;
    }
```

Here C_SAMPLING_STEP is kept 4. And the idea is to basically reach from all sides and terminate the loop once a change from 0 to 255 is detected.

Is there any other method which can be more efficient and robust?

Update: I have tried using different radius for morphological closing operation
with MORPH_ELLIPSE of Size(5,5) the output is:

[image]
[image]

and Size(7,7)

[image]
[image]

and Size(9,9)

[image]

This solves the problem to some extent, however I am not sure which size to use as the noise in the data varies quite alot (depending on the pose of the hand).

Comment: Did you try varying the radius of the closing operation?  It really seems like the image you posted would clean up nicely when closed.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, I have tried different values and it is working with different radius with different data.

Comment: So that solved your problem?  Or is there still an issue?

Comment: Does the size of the hand stay relatively constant in the image?  You could look at the ratio of white to black...  If not perhaps you could look at the ratio of white to black inside some kind of rough bounding box enclosing all the white points

Comment: Also you could try passing findContours the [CV_RETR_EXTERNAL](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) parameter to have it only find outer contrours, that might go faster and then you only need to make sure that a solid white border surrounds the hand, holes on the inside are fine.

Comment: yes, I am normalizing all images to a size of 64x64 pixels. The tracking is fairly robust as well, as a result of which the segmentation regions stays almost the same. Thanks for your help, i will try that now.